# Must the grpc client and server run on the same system?

Tags: linux, windows, server, client, grpc

I have a question for help. Must the grpc client and server run on the same system? If the client runs on windows, is it feasible for the server to run on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

gRPC (gRPC Remote Procedure Calls[2](https://grpc.io/)) also known as Google Remote Procedure Call (or good Remote Procedure Call) is an open source remote procedure call (RPC)

The data streams are distributed over http/2 so it doesn't matter what os the server or client has.

[gRPC wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRPC)

> It generates cross-platform client and server bindings for many languages. Most common usage scenarios include connecting services in a microservices style architecture, or connecting mobile device clients to backend services.

> gRPC is a modern open source high performance Remote Procedure Call (RPC) framework that can run in any environment.

[Why gRPC?](https://grpc.io/)

> gRPC is a powerful framework for working with Remote Procedure Calls. RPCs allow you to write code as though it will be run on a local computer, even though it may be executed on another computer.

The client and server can have different os, languages ​​or hardware it is like a model framework, that works over http/2.

let's imagine it's a web application the server can run on windows, mac, linux, etc.
we can use different databases and also different programming languages ​​in the end but we use a browser and it doesn't matter what kind of os we use on the client to get the result on the browser.

The gRPC protocol was designed to support services that change over time. In general, the additions to the gRPC services and methods are not breaking changes. Non-Breaking Changes allow existing clients to continue working without changes. Changing or deleting gRPC services are breaking changes. When gRPC services experience breaking changes, the clients consuming that service need to be updated and redeployed.

**in the end we always do the same thing.
we store/manage data and then try to send it to a device or object.
the communication protocol is important not the languages, because you can change and use different languages.
Can the end node(user,server,service,etc..) manage/handle my message/transaction**

Comment: Thank you @Blockchain Office, and i also have a doubt, Do the client and server need to use the same version of grpc?

Comment: Yes, in the past, our client and server were on windows, but now the server is on Linux, but the version of grpc used is different from that of the client. Is this feasible?

Comment: Yes it is feasible.